# How to set (reset) PXE binary filename in pfsense?

Tags: dhcp, freebsd, pxe, pfsense

I am trying to load `lpxelinux.0` instead of `pxelinux.0` in pfSense, and configured it in `default bios filename` setting:

[image]

Unfortunately, server still sends `pxelinux.0` as a filename:

[image]

How to fix?

How to check configuration in pfSense console?

**UPDATE**

Restarting DHCP server didn't help. Setting this name in all three settings also didn't help.

Comment: Not sure if this will help: https://github.com/pfsense/FreeBSD-ports/search?q=pxelinux.0 This looks like a `man` page to the `pxe-pdhcp` command, which you may try to run for more debugging options.

Answer (score 0):

your problem could be that you are probably booting from another PXE server alive in your network...

Comment: Your answer sounds kind of speculative.  If so, it might be more appropriate as a comment.  If it turns out to be the solution, it could be expanded into a definitive answer.  [from review](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/544163)

Comment: my answer is not a speculation; it offers the "most likely scenario" for solving OP's issue.

Comment: Maybe change "could" and "probably" (and not use both)?

Comment: You finding something more productive to do and giving all of us a break sounds much better.

Comment: Whatever.  Didn't know if you were aware that your answer was in the low quality review queue, where the scrutiny could attract downvotes.